# Windows Server 2008 R2 Datacenter as workstation, what sort of license do I need?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, license

Once upon a time my air-gapped desktop PC ran 2008 R2 DC (among other OS) using a free product key. That partition still exists, but I haven't used it in years and since the hardware has been upgraded repeatedly in the meantime, my old key is no longer valid. I am no longer part of the MSDNAA and I don't have any other keys, so evidently I need to buy a new one.

I've been trying to understand Microsoft's licensing model but have been unable to do so since none of the explanations seem to consider my case where the OS is installed on an ordinary desktop PC rather than used as an actual network server. I'm hoping someone can clear up a couple of things for me:

- Is a user CAL or a device CAL better suited for me?
- Does each CAL come with exactly one product key?
- Is there any point in getting multiple CALs?
- Are some CALs valid for both 2008 and 2008 R2?
- What would I do if I unexpectedly had to replace hardware or migrate to a new PC entirely?

Comment: The license key can still be used.  Use the phone activation method.  Windows 2008 and Windows 2008 R2 are entirely two different releases and have their own licenses.  In other words you cannot use a Windows 2008 license to activate Windows Server 2008 R2; You cannot purchase legitimate Windows Server 2008 R2 keys in 2021; Windows Server licenses don’t have the same restrictions as OEM Windows keys.

Comment: Is [this](https://softwarekeep.eu/en/microsoft-windows-server-2008-r2-datacenter.html) not a genuine license?

Comment: It’s probably a gray license.  Most “wholesale” websites sell gray licenses.  That is significantly cheaper than any legitimate copy of Windows Server should be